# How to replace this weird faucet aerator?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, sink

I'm trying to remove my aerator but it doesn't seem like the standard one that you can unscrew it with a delta key or a wretch. I guess the issue is because the water pipe is attached to the aerator as in the first picture. Any advice on how I can get rid of this bad boy?
[image][image]

Comment: Your pictures appear to be of different faucets; which one is your faucet? The first pic seems to show that the aerator has already been removed. The second pic is out of focus but seems to show flat spots on the aerator body (which, if true, is a big hint...)

Comment: Hi, these two pics are taken from the same faucet. I took the first pic with my camera above the faucet (I pulled the aerator a bit to the side to show what I mean by "there is a black pipe attached to the aerator")

Comment: i think that you just unscrew it with your fingers

Answer (score 2):

The faucet is broken. Your faucet is of a newer type where the water flows through the spout and out the aerator via a plastic tube that runs inside of the metal "spout" (this allows manufacturers to avoid metallurgical complications related to the amount of toxic lead in the brass used for the spout).

The aerator piece has broken away from its attachment point; the piece that it used to thread onto is stuck in the aerator itself.

Comment: I agree something is broken , never seen a aerator that was soft plumbed on that type of faucet.

Comment: So this is not the kind of aerator which I can just buy a pipe wrench and unscrew?

Comment: It is **normally** unscrewable. The male threaded part that it would normally unscrew from is broken off and stuck inside the aerator itself. The faucet is toast and must be replaced; or you can choose to live with it as it is... sorry. It's a cheap imported (read- Chinese) faucet and this is the result.